# Product of two CAT($\kappa$) spaces is CAT($\kappa$) for $\kappa \ge 0$

Tags: metric-geometry

I would like to see a "metric proof" that if two metric spaces $X$ and $Y$ are CAT($\kappa$) for some $\kappa \ge 0$, then so is their product. I would be satisfied to see a proof for $X=Y=S^2$.

By "metric proof" I mean one which does not rely on Riemannian geometry, but rather only uses Alexandrov (metric) geometry. I already understand the case where $\kappa \le 0$ (where in fact the product will only be CAT($\text{max}(0,\kappa)$).

Comment: What is ${\rm CAT}[k]$ and their product ?

Comment: A CAT($\kappa$) space is a geodesic space all of whose geodesic triangles of perimeter less than $2D_\kappa$ satisfy the CAT$(\kappa)$ inequality. Here $D_\kappa= +\infty$ if $\kappa \leq 0$ or $\frac{\pi}{\kappa}$ if $\kappa > 0$. One version of the CAT$(\kappa$) inequality says that if one takes such a triangle in $X$ and a comparison triangle in the model plane of curvature $\kappa$, then the Alexandrov angles in the triangle in $X$ are no greater than the corresponding angles of the comparison triangle.

Comment: The product of two metric spaces $X\times Y$ has the usual cartesian product $X \times Y$ as its underlying set, and the metric is defined in the expected way: $$ d_{X \times Y}((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))^2 = d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2 $$

Comment: Sorry, in the first comment, $ \frac{\pi}{\kappa}$ should have been $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\kappa}}$. $X$ is the CAT$(\kappa)$ space under discussion.

Answer (score 0):

In ${\rm CAT}\ [k]$-space, two points of distance smaller than
$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{k}}$ have unique geodesic.

So if $\mathbb{S}^2\times \mathbb{S}^2$ is ${\rm CAT}\ [k]$-space
s.t. $0<k<1$, then assume that $(p,q),\ (-p,q_\epsilon)$ s.t.
$|q-q_\epsilon|=\epsilon$ and $\sqrt{ \pi^2+\epsilon^2
}<\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{k}}$. Note that there are infinitely many
shortest paths between them.